# Updating session without reloading page with AJAX Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I am working on a cart system and this is a kind of blueprint I am trying to make work. So whenever the user clicks the Add button session for the specific assignment will be created and listed on the page. I neglected increase amount/decrease amount/delete/ logic for the sake of simplicity. The problem is I can not implement logic where it will store session without refreshing the page.

This is my Controller:

```
    public function storeAssignmentSession($id, Request $request) {
    $assignmentId = $request->input('assignment_id');
    $quantity = 1; // Default quantity is 1
    $assignment = Assignment::find($assignmentId);

    if ($assignment) {
        $taskSession = session('session_' . $id, []);

        $existingKey = null;
        foreach ($taskSession as $key => $sessionData) {
            if ($sessionData['assignment_id'] === $assignment->id) {
                $existingKey = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($existingKey !== null) {
            $taskSession[$existingKey]['quantity'] += $quantity;
        } else {
            $taskSession[] = [
                'assignment_id' => $assignment->id,
                'assignment_name' => $assignment->assignment_name,
                'assignment_status' => $assignment->assignment_status,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
            ];
        }

        session(['session_' . $id => $taskSession]);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is my Route:

```
Route::post('/task/{id}/store-assignment-session', [Taskmanager::class, 'storeAssignmentSession'])->name('store_assignment_session');
```

This is my Blade:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle the "Add" button click
    $(".add-assignment").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
        
        var assignmentId = $(this).data("assignment-id");
        var taskId = {{$task->id}};
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/task/' + taskId + '/store-assignment-session',
            data: { assignment_id: assignmentId },
            success: function(response) {
                // Load the page to refresh the content
                location.reload();

                // Log the session data in the console
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Failed to add assignment to session.');
            }
        });
    });
    
    // Handle the "Subtract" button click
    $(".subtract-assignment").click(function() {
        var key = $(this).data("key");
        var taskId = {{$task->id}};
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/task/' + taskId + '/subtracting-assignment-session/' + key,
            success: function(response) {
                // Load the page to refresh the content
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Failed to subtract assignment from session.');
            }
        });
    });
    
    // Handle the "Add" button click
    $(".add-assignment").click(function() {
        var key = $(this).data("key");
        var taskId = {{$task->id}};
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/task/' + taskId + '/adding-assignment-session/' + key,
            success: function(response) {
                // Load the page to refresh the content
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Failed to add assignment to session.');
            }
        });
    });
    
    // Handle the "Delete" button click
    $(".delete-assignment").click(function() {
        var key = $(this).data("key");
        var taskId = {{$task->id}};
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/task/' + taskId + '/delete-assignment-session/' + key,
            success: function(response) {
                // Load the page to refresh the content
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Failed to delete assignment from session.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am new to AJAX. I need to store the session and list it on the screen without reloading the page. However, whatever I do page gets updated. Can please suggest what should I do in this situation?

Comment: When you call `session([])` the value is immediately created and is retrievable in your next AJAX request without the need to reload. If you want to make calls to your server and not reload the page, you should be using `return response()->json([...])` instead of `return redirect()->back();`

Answer (score 1):

1. like @Linesofcode commented, you must response as array, not redirect or render page
2. Are you using authentication system from Laravel?

Because each user have a session key, so you can not access session user from normal request.

You must add `csrf token` in ajax reques. To Laravel can know who is logging

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  
In script

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Please reconfig ajax header